# Browser discrepancy

Tags: php, html, browser, submit, contactus

when im trying to test it with safari and ie it doesnt display any result :( instead an empty page loads.,same also with my contact form.,

```
<html  lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
         <body>
         <div id="content"><br/>
                Fill out your criteria for searching and see the result below<br/><br/>

          <?php

        include('connection.php');

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable") or die (mysql_error());

            if(isset($_POST['btnSearch']))
                {
                $query = $_POST['budget'];
                $query1 = $_POST['location'];
                //$query2 = $_POST['bedroom'];
                $query3 = $_POST['building'];

                {
                    if (isset($_POST['1br'])&&
                        $_POST['1br']=='1BR'){
                            $query2=$_POST['1br'];
                                }
                }

                 {
                    if (isset($_POST['2br'])&&
                        $_POST['2br']=='2BR'){
                            $query2=$_POST['2br'];
                                }
                }

                 {
                    if (isset($_POST['3br'])&&
                        $_POST['3br']=='3BR'){
                            $query2=$_POST['3br'];
                                }
                }

                $min_length = 0;
                if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
                { 
                $query = htmlspecialchars($query); mysql_real_escape_string($query);
                $row_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE(`location` like'%".$query1."%') && (`sale_price` like '%".$query."%') && (`numberoftb` like '%".$query2."%') && (`building_name` like '%".$query3."%')");
                if(mysql_num_rows($row_result) > 0)
                {
                while($result = mysql_fetch_array($row_result))
                { 

                echo'<span class="sub_header">TRANSACTION NUMBER:</span> '.$result['transaction_number'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>LOCATION:</span> '.$result['location'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>FOR LEASE:</span> '.$result['for_lease'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>FOR SALE:</span> '.$result['for_sale'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>BUILDING NAME:</span> '.$result['building_name'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>DEVELOPER:</span> '.$result['developer'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>NUMBER OF BEDROOM:</span> '.$result['numberoftb'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>NUMBER OF ROOM:</span> '.$result['numberofroom'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>FULLY FURNISHED:</span> '.$result['fullyfurnished'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>WITH BALCONY:</span> '.$result['withbalcony'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>SALE PRICE:</span> '.$result['sale_price'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>LEASE PRICE:</span> '.$result['lease_price'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>DESCRIPTION:</span> '.$result['description'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>FLOOR AREA:</span> '.$result['floor_area'];
                echo'<span class="sub_header"><br/>MORE DETAILS:</span><a href="view.php?transaction_number='.$result['transaction_number'].'">View</a></td>';
                echo'<br/><br/>';
                }}
                else{ 
                echo'<span class="header">No Result</span>'; 
                } }
                else{ 
                echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
                }
              }      

        ?>

        </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <section class="widget">
                    <center><h4 class="widgettitle"><br/>Search!</h4><br/>
                    <form name="searchcondo" method="post" action="" >
                        <span class="sub_header">Enter the BUDGET you want:</span><br /><input type="text" name="budget" maxlength="50" size="30"><br/>
                        <span class="sub_header">Building Name:</span><br /><input type="text" name="building" maxlength="80" size="30"><br/>
                        <span class="sub_header">Number of BEDROOMS:</span><br /><input type="checkbox" name="1br" value="1BR">1BR<input type="checkbox" name="2br" value="2BR">2BR<input type="checkbox" name="3br" value="3BR">3BR<br/>
                        <span class="sub_header">Location:</span><br /><input type="text" name="location" maxlength="80" size="30"><br/>
                                    <br /><input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search">
                    </form>
                    </center>
                </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I already uploaded it and the above code works with FireFox and Google Chrome.
Whats the possible solution with Safari and IE?
Im new to this Please help me.. Thanks.. :(

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? Is it giving an error, or not loading, or...?

Comment: mysql extension has been deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead :)

Comment: Is it giving you an error when you try to load it - are errors turned on? Also, I suggest re-adding the PHP/SQL code to your post, as it could be necessary to find the fault in the code.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No error, its just that the moment i click the button it doesnt display anything or load any., this happens when im using safari and ie browser.

Comment: Why why why? :( any of my button in the site doesnt work including my contact us page, :(..

Answer (score 0):

Try to close `<div id="sidebar">` after `</section>`

Comment: Please inform about IE & Safari version

Comment: safari is 5.1.7 and IE 10

Comment: oh hello, btw site is here www.omniboostproperties.com

Comment: My browser inform me about null response, when I submit any form.Check error.log of your web server. There is error in php code (or php environment).